# How can I raise an error if input is NaN?

Tags: python

I am trying to implement an algorithm that converts a decimal number to is binary equivalent.

This is what I have.

```
def binary_converter(n):
    if n < 0:raise ValueError, "Invalid input"
    if n >255:raise ValueError, "Invalid input"
    if n > 1:
        binary_converter(n//2)
        print(n % 2,end = '')

# Take decimal number from user
dec = int(input("Enter an integer: "))
binary_converter(dec)
```

My question is about these lines:

```
    if n < 0:raise ValueError, "Invalid input"
    if n >255:raise ValueError, "Invalid input"
```

I am attempting to validate the input contains only digits 0-9.

How can I achieve that validation?

Comment: Sorry are you saying this doesn't work or you want a code review? there is another site for that: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: SO is not for code review. If you have a problem please specify it so we can help.

Comment: Are you asking about a `float('nan')` or any input that isn't made up of only the characters `0-9`? Also do you mean to have the bottom 3 lines indented like that?

Comment: @SCB Yes, 0-9 only.

Comment: Trying to make your code somewhat functional instead of obviously wrong and construct some form of question out of your comments.

Comment: @EdChum Noted, Thanks for the link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of methods. One of which is using the strings `.isdigit()`. The general problem with `.isdigit()` is that it doesn't work on negatives, however with your code, it really isn't a problem. Try replacing your input with the following custom function:

```
def positive_int_input():
    s = input("Enter an integer: ")
    if not s.isdigit():
        raise ValueError("Input is not a positive integer")
    else:
        return int(s)
```

A few examples:

```
positive_int_input()
#   Enter an integer: 42
#-> 42

positive_int_input()
#   Enter an integer: 3.14
#   ValueError: Input is not an integer

positive_int_input()
#   Enter an integer: Hello World!
#   ValueError: Input is not an integer
```

That being said:

```
int("Some String")
# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Some String'
```

An Error is returned regardless, so I don't know exactly what you think is wrong with your code besides fixing up the indenting.

Comment: Thank you. I'll correct the indenting part. I began learning python 8 days ago